# JUnit 5 major features outline

Tags: junit, junit5

Could you please outline new major features of JUnit 5 in comparison to JUnit 4?
What are new annotations, if any, and what they are used for (if few words)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUnit 5 **programming model** remained almost unchanged. We still have to use annotations to declare test and life-cycle methods.
At first sight there are no big changes. However, they exists:

- Neither test classes nor test methods need to be public.
- `@Test` annotation does not have additional parameters
- Life-cycle annotations were renamed

  - `@BeforeAll / @AfterAll`
  - `@BeforeEach / @AfterEach`
- `@Disabled` is the analogous to JUnit 4’s `@Ignore`

Also some changes was made for `Assertions` and `Assumptions`:

- The optional message is now the last parameter
- Assertion messages can be lazily evaluated using `Supplier<String>`
- Now it is possible to assert boolean condition using `BooleanSupplier`

Also JUnit 5 introduced some new concepts into programming model:

- Tagging and filtering

  `@Tag` and `@Tags` used to declare tags for filtering tests, either at the class or method level; analogous to Categories in JUnit 4
- `@Nested` test classes

  For better grouping and organization, shared initialization state.
- `@DisplayName`

  Allow to declare custom display names — with spaces, special characters, and even emojis — that will be displayed by test runners and test reporting.
- Dynamic tests

  Useful when you need to run the same set of tests on many different input values or configurations.

JUnit 5 doen't support anymore `Runners` and `Rules`. These partially competing concepts have been replaced by a single consistent **extension model**.
Since test execution follows a certain life cycle. And each phase of that life cycle that can be extended is represented by an interface. Extensions can express interest in certain phases in that they implement the corresponding interface(s).
Using extensions you can implement:

- Conditional test execution

  - `TestExecutionCondition`
  - `ContainerExecutionCondition`
- Constructor and methods parameters resolution (dependency injection)

  - `ParameterResolver`
- Exception handling

  - `TestExecutionExceptionHandler`
- Handle test life-cycle

  - `TestInstancePostProcessor`
  - `BeforeAllCallback`
  - `BeforeEachCallback`
  - `BeforeTestExecutionCallback`
  - `AfterTestExecutionCallback`
  - `AfterEachCallback`
  - `AfterAllCallback`